# Customer Snapshot

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a snapshot of customer table and also add reference date when the snapshot was taken.

```
select * from customer_dump;
select * from customer_snapshot;
select count(*) into b 
from user_tables 
where table_name = upper('customer_snapshot_dump');
if b = 1 then
  execute immediate 'drop table customer_snapshot_dump purge';
end if;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table customer_snapshot_dump as (select sysdate as SNAPSHOT_DATE,* from customer_snapshot)';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table customer_snapshot purge';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'create table customer_snapshot as (SELECT * FROM customer_dump
UNION
SELECT * FROM customer_snapshot_dump)';
end;
```

But the snapshot_date will only make it union all the data. How can the snapshot_date be ignored in the union but still added to the table?

Comment: You'd need to list out the columns in the table when building the `UNION` since you can't use `*`.  If you need that to be dynamic, you could query the data dictionary (`all_tab_columns`) and use the `listagg` function to produce a comma-separated list of the columns in the `customer_snapshot` table.

Comment: Yes, i could easily list it all and exclude snapshot_date but i want the snapshot_date to be added when taking the snapshot.

Comment: You're already adding the `snapshot_date` when creating `customer_snapshot_dump`.  If you want to include the column when you're creating the `customer_snapshot` table, you'd need to add the column to the `select` list from `customer_dump`.  I don't know what value you'd want (`null`, `sysdate`, etc.)

Comment: The customer dumb already has the snapshot_date column. The issue now is When i run this daily it re-adds all the data from customer_snapshot_dumb to customer_snapshot because of the snapshot_date column ('sys_date' It will always be different daily)

Comment: Maybe I'm having trouble following you-- perhaps some sample data, expected results, removing any code that isn't necessary to reproduce the problem, etc. would help.  If I'm understanding you now, you'd want to list out the non-`snapshot_date` columns in the `union`.  As I said initially, you could do that with `listagg` if you want to make it dynamic.  If you want `snapshot_date` to be in the `customer_snapshot` table, you could add it to the outer `select` or do a join to one or both of the tables you're unioning.